# Python. Pushing values to the dictionary in dictionary

Tags: python

I am getting values from some source using which I need to create a dictionary of dictionary.
To solve such a task in PHP I would just write a `for` loop and:

```
$arr[ifIndex][$key] = $val
```

I do not need to bother if  a `$key` value really exists in my associative array - it will be created if it isn't.
In Python though you get a key error so I have to check that and add a dictionary if it isn't there:

```
if ifIndex in data:
     data[ifIndex][entry] = val.prettyPrint()
else:
     data[ifIndex] = { entry: val.prettyPrint() }
```

To me that looks very ugly and I think there is way of doing that as simple as in a PHP example.

Comment: Look into using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), it was made just for this purpose (among a few other nifty features).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = collections.defaultdict(dict)
a['b']['c'] = 'd'
```

returns

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'b': {'c': 'd'}})
```